# How to detect the end of a hover transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I detect the end of a :hover transition? I already tried the code I find everywhere for the transition which is:

```
document.getElementById('title-text').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
function(e) {

console.log('done');

});
```

Comment: With your logic, I think you may be able to use the mouse out event for executing your code when the mouse leaves

Comment: and in your code try to change it with `.addEventListener("transitionend", (event) => {
  // code here
}, false);`

Comment: document.getElementById("title-text").onmouseout = function() {console.log('done')}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should watch for the `transitionend` event listener, cause it will work only after the transition is finished, not when the user pulls the mouse out of the element.

Someone mentioned to watch for `mouseout` event, **don't** do that.

```js
document.getElementById('title-text').addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  console.log('done');
});
```

```css
#title-text {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 4s ease-in-out;
}

#title-text:hover {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='title-text'>This is Text</div>
```

**Also** if you want that to execute only once, do this with `jQuery` `.one()` method:

```js
$('#title-text').one('transitionend', function(e) {
  console.log('done');
});
```

```css
#title-text {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 4s ease-in-out;
}

#title-text:hover {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='title-text'>This is Text</div>
```

Comment: Hi, how can I focus on only one transition, as I have several. Thanks.

Comment: @TowkirAhmed By that you mean in this answer or the other answer.

Comment: @TudorPopescu in this answer there are two snippets, the second snippet is implemented with `jQuery`'s `.one()` method

Answer (score 1):

In javascript use a event listener to detect mouseout

```html
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {} )
```

Or

```html
    <element onmouseout='functionname()'> </element>
```